# java.io.IOException: Failed to bind error on ActiveMQ service start

Tags: activemq-classic

I am configuring a new install of ActiveMQ 5.15.10 on a RHEL 7.7 AWS instance. When the process starts I get this error:

```
[ec2-user@ip-***-***-***-*** activemq]$ more data/activemq.log
2019-10-30 17:36:45,784 | INFO  | Refreshing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@4667ae56: startup date [Wed Oct 30 17:36:45 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,568 | INFO  | Using Persistence Adapter: KahaDBPersistenceAdapter[/opt/activemq/data/kahadb] | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,628 | INFO  | KahaDB is version 6 | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.MessageDatabase | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,652 | INFO  | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/***-***-***-***/tmp_storage] started | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,821 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.10 (***-***-***-***, ID:ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal-36686-1572457006663-0:1) is starting | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,849 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: tcp://ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal:61616?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,851 | INFO  | Connector openwire started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,855 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: amqp://ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal:5672?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,856 | INFO  | Connector amqp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,859 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: stomp://ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal:61613?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,861 | INFO  | Connector stomp started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,864 | INFO  | Listening for connections at: mqtt://ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal:1883?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.TransportServerThreadSupport | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,865 | INFO  | Connector mqtt started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,870 | INFO  | Starting Jetty server | org.apache.activemq.transport.WebTransportServerSupport | main
2019-10-30 17:36:46,951 | INFO  | Creating Jetty connector | org.apache.activemq.transport.WebTransportServerSupport | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,043 | WARN  | ServletContext@o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7b420819{/,null,STARTING} has uncovered http methods for path: / | org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,091 | INFO  | Listening for connections at ws://ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal:61614?maximumConnections=1000&wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600 | org.apache.activemq.transport.ws.WSTransportServer | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,092 | INFO  | Connector ws started | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,093 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.10 (***-***-***-***, ID:ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal-36686-1572457006663-0:1) started | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,094 | INFO  | For help or more information please see: http://activemq.apache.org | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,095 | WARN  | Store limit is 102400 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data/kahadb only has 47858 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 47858 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,096 | WARN  | Temporary Store limit is 51200 mb (current store usage is 0 mb). The data directory: /opt/activemq/data only has 47858 mb of usable space. - resetting to maximum available disk space: 47858 mb | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,726 | INFO  | ActiveMQ WebConsole available at http://***-***-***-***:8161/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2019-10-30 17:36:47,726 | INFO  | ActiveMQ Jolokia REST API available at http://***-***-***-***:8161/api/jolokia/ | org.apache.activemq.web.WebConsoleStarter | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,001 | WARN  | Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /***-***-***-***:8161 | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,013 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.10 (***-***-***-***, ID:ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal-36686-1572457006663-0:1) is shutting down | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,014 | INFO  | Connector openwire stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,015 | INFO  | Connector amqp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,016 | INFO  | Connector stomp stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,017 | INFO  | Connector mqtt stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,021 | INFO  | Connector ws stopped | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnector | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,024 | INFO  | PListStore:[/opt/activemq/data/***-***-***-***/tmp_storage] stopped | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.plist.PListStoreImpl | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,025 | INFO  | Stopping async queue tasks | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,025 | INFO  | Stopping async topic tasks | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,026 | INFO  | Stopped KahaDB | org.apache.activemq.store.kahadb.KahaDBStore | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,046 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.10 (***-***-***-***, ID:ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal-36686-1572457006663-0:1) uptime 1.495 seconds | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,047 | INFO  | Apache ActiveMQ 5.15.10 (***-***-***-***, ID:ip-***-***-***-***.ec2.internal-36686-1572457006663-0:1) is shutdown | org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerService | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,048 | INFO  | Closing org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1@4667ae56: startup date [Wed Oct 30 17:36:45 UTC 2019]; root of context hierarchy | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1 | main
2019-10-30 17:36:48,049 | ERROR | Failed to load: class path resource [activemq.xml], reason: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /***-***-***-***:8161 | org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory | main
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'invokeStart' defined in class path resource [jetty.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.io.IOException: Failed to bind to /3.231.235.30:8161
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:737)[spring-beans-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)[spring-context-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)[spring-context-4.3.24.RELEASE.jar:4.3.24.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:64)[xbean-spring-4.14.jar:4.14]
        at org.apache.xbean.spring.context.ResourceXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ResourceXmlApplicationContext.java:52)[xbean-spring-4.14.jar:4.14]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory$1.<init>(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createApplicationContext(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:104)[activemq-spring-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.xbean.XBeanBrokerFactory.createBroker(XBeanBrokerFactory.java:67)[activemq-spring-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:71)[activemq-broker-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.broker.BrokerFactory.createBroker(BrokerFactory.java:54)[activemq-broker-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.StartCommand.runTask(StartCommand.java:87)[activemq-console-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)[activemq-console-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.runTask(ShellCommand.java:154)[activemq-console-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.AbstractCommand.execute(AbstractCommand.java:63)[activemq-console-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.command.ShellCommand.main(ShellCommand.java:104)[activemq-console-5.15.10.jar:5.15.10]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)[:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)[:1.8.0_191]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[:1.8.0_191]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)[:1.8.0_191]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.runTaskClass(Main.java:262)[activemq.jar:5.15.10]
        at org.apache.activemq.console.Main.main(Main.java:115)[activemq.jar:5.15.10]
```

It looks like the web console is logged as available, and then it tries to bind the web console port again? This is on a fresh instance with no other services or java processes running.

Please advise.

Comment: This seems like an environmental issue to me (e.g. there is a process using that port that you are unaware of). To test this theory you could restart a few times using a different random port each time instead of the default `8161`. If the problem is with multiple instances of the web server being started and trying to use the same port then the same exception will occur with each and every port you try. If the problem is with another process using `8161` then one or more of the other random ports you try should work.